# How to integrate GCC's fix-it hints into a vim-based workflow?

Tags: vimdiff, errorformat

Modern GCC provides the `-fdiagnostics-generate-patch` flag:

```
   Options to Control Diagnostic Messages Formatting
[...]
       -fdiagnostics-generate-patch
           Print fix-it hints to stderr in unified diff format, after any diagnostics are printed.
```

For example, given this intentionally erroneous C program:

```
int main()
{
    int f1;
    fl = printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

`gcc -fdiagnostics-generate-patch` produces the usual output:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:5: error: ‘fl’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘f1’?
    4 |     fl = printf("Hello, World!\n");
      |     ^~
      |     f1
main.c:4:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:4:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    4 |     fl = printf("Hello, World!\n");
      |          ^~~~~~
main.c:4:10: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
main.c:1:1: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
  +++ |+#include <stdio.h>
    1 | int main()
```

followed by a `diff`-like patch:

```
--- main.c
+++ main.c
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
+#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     int f1;
-    fl = printf("Hello, World!\n");
+    f1 = printf("Hello, World!\n");
 }
```

which is obviously very handy when fixing small mistakes but might not always be right.

Building on how vim already makes the "edit/compile/fix cycle" smoother (`quickfix`, `:compiler`, `'errorformat'`, `:make`, ...), I was wondering if there was a way to automatically capture the suggested patch (which would have to be extracted from the regular output) and display it using `:diff` in order to allow the user to easily review and apply (`:diffget`/`:diffput`) the change, if it exists.